# How do you set up Caliburn Micro guard methods for items not in the view?

Tags: caliburn.micro

I'm trying to get Caliburn Micro going in my project and I'm having trouble understanding guard methods (`Can*`) in the context of properties that aren't bound to the view (forgive me if I'm getting my terminology wrong).

I've adapted [Tim Corey's example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laPFq3Fhs8k) to add this snippet:

```
        private bool _connected;

        public bool Connected
        {
            get { return _connected; }
            set { _connected = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Connected); }
        }

        public bool CanSayHello(bool connected)
        {
            return connected;
        }

        public void SayHello(bool connected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        }

        public bool CanClearText(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName))
            {
                Connected = false;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Connected = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
```

And the associated xaml is:

```
        <!-- Row 4 -->
        <Button x:Name="ClearText" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1">Clear Names</Button>
        <Button x:Name="SayHello" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2">Say Hello</Button>
```

The `SayHello` button is never enabled (even though it seems like it should have the same state as `CanClearText`). The intent is to use `Connected` as an intermediary property; in the application I'm putting together, the idea is that `Connected` is actually set by an external Message (from a model--not connected to a view).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546568/caliburn-micro-guard-methods-not-evaluating-on-property-change) gets to it a bit, but I'd like to avoid explicitly calling `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSayHello);` and let the Caliburn Micro framework do the work for me. I'm pretty new to this, and I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing--thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Caliburn Micro, in this particular, case might not provide a easy solution. You would have to trigger the NotifyPropertyChanged manually for the dependend properties like CanSayHello each time Connected Property changes. However, you could make use of [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) Extensions which could do the same for you, without explicitly typing the code.

For example,

```
[AlsoNotify(nameof(CanSayHello))]
public bool Connected
{
    get { return _connected; }
        set { _connected = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Connected); }
}
```

This, with the help of Code weaving would do the NotifyPropertyChanged for without having to explicitly do so yourself.